# participle phrase or to-infinitive phrase

Tags: infinitives, participles

> In response to the long-term measures recommended by the School Board,
>   the then Principal initiated the Pledge Day on “Clean LA", to encourage
>   all schools to make the “Clean LA” commitment on that day.

I wonder if it sounds better to replace the to-infinitive clause with a participle clause:

> In response to the long-term measures recommended by the School Board,
>   the then Principal initiated the Pledge Day on “Clean LA", encouraging
>   all schools to make the “Clean LA” commitment on that day.

because I think it is seldom to use to-infinitive clauses after a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To encourage" and "encouraging" both sound fine to me.  There's a subtle difference:

> the Principal initiated the Pledge Day, to encourage ....

This answers the question, Why did the principal initiate the Pledge Day?

> the Principal initiated the Pledge Day, encouraging ....

This means that through initiating the Pledge Day, the principal was, in this way, encouraging....

(Note, the comma is fine.)

There's a third option:

> the Principal initiated the Pledge Day, and encouraged ....

This one suggests that perhaps the principal held an all-school assembly, where he explained the concepts and provided encouragement.

Comment: the difference is really subtle.